# Compare words in Prestashop Smarty tpl file (Cyrillic symbols)

Tags: compare, smarty, prestashop, cyrillic

ALMOST found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125918/smarty-regular-expression-match)

But as i can understand THIS `{if $haystack1|strstr:"_thestring_"}Found!{/if}` **not working** with non Latin symbols...

The problem: I need to check if string 'терминалы' exist in $payment_method.desc variable
Here is a Smarty code

(`The Variable **$payment_method.desc** contain this text 'Оплата наличными через кассы и терминалы'`):

```
{assign "desc" $payment_method.desc}
{assign "var_1" "терминалы"}
{if $desc|@mb_stristr:$var_1|@var_dump}Found!{/if}
{if $desc|@mb_strstr:$var_1|@var_dump}Found!{/if}
{if $desc|@strstr:$var_1|@var_dump}Found!{/if}
```

Same code work if use Latin symbols.

Comment: Hello. Did you solve this issue??  Did answer help you?? Regards

Comment: Nop is not solved... for now i use dirty hack just using Latin symbols which is similar to Cyrillic. I compare just part of word "терминалы" so "терм" is the same letters in latin...

Answer (score 1):

Smarty var declaration uses PHP internal encoding.

You should check the last parameter of `mb_*` functions related to encoding. Check this: [mb_strstr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strstr.php)

This post could help you too: [php case-insensitive comparison of russian characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914158/php-case-insensitive-comparison-of-russian-characters)

If you are sure that string has Russian characters you should consider convert from "Windows-1251" encoding.

Any PHP function could be called from Smarty, so you could test with all of them.

Good luck.

Comment: I check how i can try to pass other parameter to Smarty function if this is possible. Russian looks good in utf-8 format so i dont think convert to convert from "Windows-1251" will help...

Comment: You can pass more than one parameter to smarty function using : like this: {$value|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}. Russian maybe "looks" good but when comparing chars don't match.

Comment: i try this part from begining, {$var:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}... and its not help.